# Dynamic variables in HTML and Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using `ng-repeat` through a list of objects that consist of displayNames and variables. For example, here is an example fields list:

```
"fields": [
    {"displayName": "Company Name", "variable": "name"},
    {"displayName": "Location of Product", "variable": "location"},
]
```

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <label class="control-label">{{field.displayName}}</label>
    model.{{field.variable}}
</div>
```

I want `model.{{field.variable}}` to display the value of the `model.variable` value. So for example, if `field.displayName` is "Company Name", then I want to display `model.name`.

I tried wrapping it all in curly braces `{{model.{{field.variable}}}}` but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the **bracket notation** when you have a dynamic key.

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <label class="control-label">{{ field.displayName }}</label>
    {{ model[field.variable] }}
</div>
```